# PySide6 QAbstractTableModel not updating on dataChanged

Tags: python, pyside6, qabstracttablemodel

### Problem at hand

I a created a QAbstractTableModel to display a pandas dataframe which in turn is populated from a CSV file. In practice this application will be running in a CPython environment in a .NET application, but for now I am developing in PyCharm and running it there as well.

I need to process items row by row and update status while processing, problem is that the Status column is never updated.

The UI is not updating at all during the execution of the program, but it does when it is finished processing. When finished I see the expected results for the Status column update from None to their expected state Finished for all but row 1, 7 and 9, which report Error as expected in this case.

The issue reproduces both for the application in PyCharm during development as when ran in production environment (also for the minimal working example below).

I can see that the dataChanged signal is emitted properly from my logs.

### Minimal example

Below I tried to create a minimal working example of my code (excluding the CSV parsing and excluding the real process, for which I tried to mimic so it should run on your end as well:

main.py

```py
from enum import Enum
from pathlib import Path
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QTableView,
)
from PySide6.QtCore import (
    QAbstractTableModel,
    QCoreApplication,
    QFile,
    QModelIndex,
    QPersistentModelIndex,
    QObject,
    Qt,
)
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from typing import Union, Any, Optional

# Make sure to import clr so we can import System.InvalidOperationException to catch (some) external application
# internal exceptions
import clr
from System import InvalidOperationException

import logging.handlers
import os
import pandas as pd
import socket
import sys
import time
import random

# Create a basic logger
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Console handler (RayStations Execution Details)
# Make sure to log to stdout instead of stderr to circumvent ERROR prefix in RayStation
c_handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
c_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
c_format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
c_handler.setFormatter(c_format)
logger.addHandler(c_handler)

# Define some constants normally imported
COLUMNS = {
    "CLINICAL_ID": "Clinical Id",
    "RETAIN_SAFE_PRIVATE_ATTRIBUTES": "Retain Safe Private Attributes",
    "RETAIN_UIDS": "Retain UIDs",
    "RETAIN_INSITUTION_IDENTITY": "Retain Institution Identity",
    "RETAIN_DEVICE_IDENTITY": "Retain Device Identity",
    "RETAIN_DATES": "Retain Dates",
    "ANONYMIZED_ID": "Anonymized Id",
    "ANONYMIZED_NAME": "Anonymized Name",
}

COLUMN_TO_ANONYMIZATION_FIELD_MAPPING = {
    COLUMNS["RETAIN_DATES"]: "RetainLongitudinalTemporalInformationFullDatesOption",
    COLUMNS["RETAIN_DEVICE_IDENTITY"]: "RetainDeviceIdentityOption",
    COLUMNS["RETAIN_INSITUTION_IDENTITY"]: "RetainInstitutionIdentityOption",
    COLUMNS["RETAIN_UIDS"]: "RetainUIDs",
    COLUMNS["RETAIN_SAFE_PRIVATE_ATTRIBUTES"]: "RetainSafePrivateOption",
}


class STATUS(Enum):
    ERROR = "Error"
    PROCESSING = "Processing"
    SUCCESS = "Finished"
    WARNING = "Warning"


class CopyToResearchModel(QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[QObject] = None) -> None:
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._data = None

        # Wire up a slot to debug and show dataChanged is emitted properly
        self.dataChanged.connect(self.debug_datachanged_slot)

    def debug_datachanged_slot(self, first, last):
        # Helper to show dataChanged signal is emitted
        logger.info(f"dataChanged() emitted with ({first}, {last})")

    def get_dataframe(self):
        return self._data

    def set_dataframe(self, dataframe: pd.DataFrame):

        self._data = dataframe

        # Mimic DefaultAnonymizationOptions return value
        from dataclasses import dataclass

        @dataclass
        class DAO:
            RetainDeviceIdentityOption: bool = True
            RetainInstitutionIdentityOption: bool = False
            RetainLongitudinalTemporalInformationFullDatesOption: bool = False
            RetainLongitudinalTemporalInformationModifiedDatesOption: bool = False
            RetainPatientCharacteristicsOption: bool = False
            RetainSafePrivateOption: bool = False
            RetainUIDs: bool = False

            # Mimic behavior since connect.connect_cpython.PyScriptObject object does not have (default)
            # __getattribute__ function, but uses __getattr__ instead. We rely on this function to retrieve
            # attributes dynamically, since we can not reference them
            # dynamically using dao.FieldName
            def __getattr__(self, item):
                return self.__getattribute__(item)

        dao = DAO()

        # Set defaults when not set:
        for (column, field) in COLUMN_TO_ANONYMIZATION_FIELD_MAPPING.items():
            self._data[column].fillna(
                dao.__getattr__(field),
                inplace=True,
            )

        # Add status column as first column
        if not self._data.empty:
            self._data.insert(loc=0, column="Status", value=None)

        # Signal redraw is required
        self.layoutChanged.emit()

    def setData(
        self,
        index: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex],
        value: Any,
        role: int = Qt.EditRole | Qt.DisplayRole,
    ) -> bool:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        if (
            not index.isValid()
            or role != Qt.EditRole
            or not (0 <= row <= self.rowCount())
            or not (0 <= column <= self.columnCount())
        ):
            return False

        self._data.iloc[row, column] = value
        self.dataChanged.emit(index, index)

        return True

    def columnCount(
        self,
        parent: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex] = ...,
    ) -> int:
        try:
            return self._data.shape[1]
        except:
            pass

        return 0

    def data(
        self,
        index: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex],
        role: Qt.ItemDataRole = ...,
    ) -> Any:
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(self._data.iloc[index.row(), index.column()])

    def headerData(
        self, section: int, orientation: Qt.Orientation, role: int = ...
    ) -> Any:
        if orientation == Qt.Horizontal and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return self._data.columns[section]

    def rowCount(
        self,
        parent: Union[QModelIndex, QPersistentModelIndex] = ...,
    ) -> int:
        try:
            return self._data.shape[0]
        except:
            pass

        return 0


class CopyToResearch(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        # Load form
        self.load_ui()

        # Find the QTbaleView and set it's model
        self.view = self.findChild(QTableView, name="tableView")
        self.model = CopyToResearchModel(self)
        self.view.setModel(self.model)

        # Make window appear on top of RayStation application window, otherwise it hides behind it
        self.setWindowState(self.windowState() & ~Qt.WindowMinimized | Qt.WindowActive)

        # Add actions to buttons
        load_button = self.findChild(QPushButton, name="loadButton")
        load_button.clicked.connect(self.load_file)

        start_button = self.findChild(QPushButton, name="startButton")
        start_button.clicked.connect(self.copy_patients)

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.fspath(Path(__file__).resolve().parent), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()

        # Explicitly set window title, apparently the definition in ui file is not honoured
        self.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.tr("Anonymize clinical patients"))

    def load_file(self):
        # Mimic loading from CSV file
        count = 10
        self.model.set_dataframe(
            pd.DataFrame(
                data=[
                    [
                        f"Clinical Id {i}",
                        f"Anonimyzed Id {i}",
                        f"Anonimyzed Name {i}",
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                        random.choice([True, False]),
                    ]
                    for i in range(1, count + 1)
                ],
                columns=[
                    "Clinical Id",
                    "Anonymized Id",
                    "Anonymized Name",
                    "Retain Dates",
                    "Retain Device Identity",
                    "Retain Institution Identity",
                    "Retain UIDs",
                    "Retain Safe Private Attributes",
                ],
            )
        )

        # Force resize to also fit column headers to fit
        self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

    def copy_patients(self):
        # Limit number of retries
        # max_retries = 3
        max_retries = 1

        # Wait time (in seconds)
        timeout = 1

        df = self.model.get_dataframe()
        for (row_index, row) in df.iterrows():
            # Determine index into model to update status
            index = self.model.index(
                row_index,
                df.columns.get_loc("Status"),
                QModelIndex(),
            )

            # Extract patient_info object by querying the patient database
            clinical_id = row[COLUMNS["CLINICAL_ID"]]
            anonymized_id = row[COLUMNS["ANONYMIZED_ID"]]

            logger.info(f"Copying patient {clinical_id} to {anonymized_id}")
            status = STATUS.PROCESSING
            self.model.setData(index, status.value)

            # Seed counter for number of tries and maximum number of retries
            tries_counter = 1
            while tries_counter <= max_retries and not status == STATUS.SUCCESS:

                # Progressive wait time
                wait_time = timeout * tries_counter

                try:

                    # Copy and anonymize patient
                    logger.info(f"Processing {clinical_id}")
                    # Insert random delay to mimic real process
                    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 3))

                    # Fire random exception(s) to mimic real process
                    if row_index % 6 == 0:
                        # Make patient 7 and every 6th thereafter fail
                        raise InvalidOperationException()
                    elif row_index % 8 == 0:
                        # Make patient 9 and every 8th thereafter fail
                        raise RuntimeError("Random runtime error")
                    else:
                        # Mimic success
                        pass

                    status = STATUS.SUCCESS
                    logger.info(f"Processed {clinical_id}")

                except InvalidOperationException:
                    # Trap System.InvalidOperationException: RaySearch.CoreUtilities.SanityCheckException: Failed to resolve IndexService
                    if tries_counter < max_retries:
                        status = STATUS.WARNING
                        logger.warning(
                            f"Error transferring patient {clinical_id}, retry in {wait_time} seconds",
                            exc_info=True,
                        )
                    else:
                        status = STATUS.ERROR
                        logger.exception(
                            f"Error transferring patient {clinical_id}, maximum retries reached"
                        )
                        break
                except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt, SyntaxError):
                    raise
                except Exception:
                    status = STATUS.ERROR
                    logger.exception(
                        f"Unexpected error transferring patient {clinical_id}"
                    )
                finally:
                    self.model.setData(index, status.value)
                    self.view.resizeColumnsToContents()

                    if not status == STATUS.SUCCESS:
                        time.sleep(wait_time)

                        # Increase try counter
                        tries_counter += 1

            logger.info(f"{status.value} processing patient {clinical_id}")


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = CopyToResearch()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

form.ui:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>CopyToResearch</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="CopyToResearch">
  <property name="windowModality">
   <enum>Qt::NonModal</enum>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Anonymize clinical patients</string>
  </property>
  <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
   <item alignment="Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignVCenter">
    <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget" native="true">
     <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="loadButton">
        <property name="acceptDrops">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
        <property name="toolTip">
         <string>Load data from file</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&amp;Load from file...</string>
        </property>
        <property name="shortcut">
         <string>Ctrl+L</string>
        </property>
        <property name="flat">
         <bool>false</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QTableView" name="tableView">
        <property name="locale">
         <locale language="English" country="Netherlands"/>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeAdjustPolicy">
         <enum>QAbstractScrollArea::AdjustToContents</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="alternatingRowColors">
         <bool>true</bool>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <widget class="QPushButton" name="startButton">
        <property name="toolTip">
         <string>Start copying patients</string>
        </property>
        <property name="text">
         <string>&amp;Start</string>
        </property>
        <property name="shortcut">
         <string>Ctrl+S</string>
        </property>
       </widget>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </widget>
   </item>
  </layout>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

### Logs

```
2022-01-27 10:09:03,810 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 1 to Anonimyzed Id 1
2022-01-27 10:09:03,811 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDED468F00>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDED468F80>)
2022-01-27 10:09:03,811 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 1
2022-01-27 10:09:04,837 - ERROR - Error transferring patient Clinical Id 1, maximum retries reached
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonathan.martens\Code\raystation-administration\copy_to_research\pyside6_qabstracttableview.py", line 298, in copy_patients
    raise InvalidOperationException()
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
2022-01-27 10:09:04,839 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04F9040>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(0,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04F90C0>)
2022-01-27 10:09:05,850 - INFO - Error processing patient Clinical Id 1
2022-01-27 10:09:05,851 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 2 to Anonimyzed Id 2
2022-01-27 10:09:05,853 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FBD80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FBF80>)
2022-01-27 10:09:05,853 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 2
2022-01-27 10:09:06,854 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 2
2022-01-27 10:09:06,854 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FBF80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(1,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FC040>)
2022-01-27 10:09:06,863 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 2
2022-01-27 10:09:06,863 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 3 to Anonimyzed Id 3
2022-01-27 10:09:06,864 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FED40>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FEEC0>)
2022-01-27 10:09:06,864 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 3
2022-01-27 10:09:06,864 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 3
2022-01-27 10:09:06,864 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FEEC0>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(2,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF04FF040>)
2022-01-27 10:09:06,872 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 3
2022-01-27 10:09:06,872 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 4 to Anonimyzed Id 4
2022-01-27 10:09:06,872 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(3,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0501D40>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(3,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0501EC0>)
2022-01-27 10:09:06,872 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 4
2022-01-27 10:09:07,872 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 4
2022-01-27 10:09:07,872 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(3,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0501EC0>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(3,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0502040>)
2022-01-27 10:09:07,879 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 4
2022-01-27 10:09:07,879 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 5 to Anonimyzed Id 5
2022-01-27 10:09:07,880 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(4,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0504D00>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(4,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0504E80>)
2022-01-27 10:09:07,880 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 5
2022-01-27 10:09:07,880 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 5
2022-01-27 10:09:07,880 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(4,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0504E80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(4,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0504F00>)
2022-01-27 10:09:07,887 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 5
2022-01-27 10:09:07,887 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 6 to Anonimyzed Id 6
2022-01-27 10:09:07,887 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(5,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0507CC0>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(5,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0507E40>)
2022-01-27 10:09:07,887 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 6
2022-01-27 10:09:08,888 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 6
2022-01-27 10:09:08,888 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(5,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0507E40>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(5,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0507FC0>)
2022-01-27 10:09:08,903 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 6
2022-01-27 10:09:08,903 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 7 to Anonimyzed Id 7
2022-01-27 10:09:08,903 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(6,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AC80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(6,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AE00>)
2022-01-27 10:09:08,903 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 7
2022-01-27 10:09:09,904 - ERROR - Error transferring patient Clinical Id 7, maximum retries reached
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonathan.martens\Code\raystation-administration\copy_to_research\pyside6_qabstracttableview.py", line 298, in copy_patients
    raise InvalidOperationException()
System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
2022-01-27 10:09:09,904 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(6,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AE00>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(6,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AE80>)
2022-01-27 10:09:10,912 - INFO - Error processing patient Clinical Id 7
2022-01-27 10:09:10,913 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 8 to Anonimyzed Id 8
2022-01-27 10:09:10,914 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(7,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050DC80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(7,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050DE00>)
2022-01-27 10:09:10,914 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 8
2022-01-27 10:09:11,915 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 8
2022-01-27 10:09:11,916 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(7,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050DE00>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(7,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050DFC0>)
2022-01-27 10:09:11,931 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 8
2022-01-27 10:09:11,932 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 9 to Anonimyzed Id 9
2022-01-27 10:09:11,932 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(8,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AF80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(8,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0510100>)
2022-01-27 10:09:11,932 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 9
2022-01-27 10:09:11,932 - ERROR - Unexpected error transferring patient Clinical Id 9
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jonathan.martens\Code\raystation-administration\copy_to_research\pyside6_qabstracttableview.py", line 301, in copy_patients
    raise RuntimeError("Random runtime error")
RuntimeError: Random runtime error
2022-01-27 10:09:11,933 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(8,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AC80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(8,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AF80>)
2022-01-27 10:09:12,944 - INFO - Error processing patient Clinical Id 9
2022-01-27 10:09:12,944 - INFO - Copying patient Clinical Id 10 to Anonimyzed Id 10
2022-01-27 10:09:12,946 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(9,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AF80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(9,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0510200>)
2022-01-27 10:09:12,946 - INFO - Processing Clinical Id 10
2022-01-27 10:09:13,947 - INFO - Processed Clinical Id 10
2022-01-27 10:09:13,948 - DEBUG - dataChanged() emitted with (<PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(9,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF050AF80>, <PySide6.QtCore.QModelIndex(9,0,0x0,CopyToResearchModel(0x2edec32a950)) at 0x000002EDF0507F40>)
2022-01-27 10:09:13,967 - INFO - Finished processing patient Clinical Id 10
```

Comment: Why do you need to update the status row by row? A dataframe and the Qt model framework is usually fast enough to update hundreds of rows in a matter of milliseconds, and adding a `time.sleep` is pointless (and also blocking). If the model size is *really* big (with dozens of columns and thousands of rows), then you could call `QApplication.processEvents()` every each "batch" of rows (not *each* row). Note that you should avoid calling `resizeColumnsToContents` at each row change, as its *very* slow for big models, since it normally considers the *whole* model to compute proper sizes.

Comment: OTOH, a couple of unrelated suggestions. 1. since PySide doesn't allow loading a UI on an existing widget (as opposed to PyQt), it's not enough to just load the UI (as it won't consider the parent layout), and you need to set the child widget as central widget: `self.central = loader.load(ui_file, self)` `self.setCentralWidget(self.central)`. 2. there's no need to use `findChild` to get widgets, as QUiLoader already creates attributes based on the object name (and that's another reason to keep reference for the widget): for instance, the table can be accessed through `self.central.tableView`.

Comment: It is a minimal example. Hence the time sleep mimicking the delay (as shown in the comments) from the process that is taking up minutes. To provide feedback to the user I therefore update status row by row and not at once.

Comment: The comment only refers to some "mimicking", they didn't make it clear what was going to happen there, and since you were mentioning CSV loading, that wasn't clear. In any case, if that process takes that much time, you should move it to a thread, otherwise the whole UI will be blocked in the meantime. Then use signals to update the model (do *NOT* directly change the model from external threads, you *must* use signals).